# Swift 3 Populating TableView from Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, nstableview

I have made a Profile class and I am attempting to have this viewcontroller save billing profile objects from the information provided by the user and then have the profiles displayed in the TableView in a list under a name the user gives. I have attempted this with arrays but decided to let that go for the reason that a dictionary seems more reasonable since I can make the profile name the key. And have that displayed in the table

However, I am having trouble populating the table with the profiles.

Any help would be really much appreciated and I am open to try any suggestions. I will provide a picture and the code

[image: Picture]

```
    var dictionary =  [String:Profile]()

    let profile1 = Profile()


    profile1.firstNameB = firstNameBill
    profile1.lastNameB = lastNameBill
    profile1.emailB = emailBill
    profile1.phoneB = phoneBill
    profile1.address1B = address1Bill
    profile1.address2B = address2Bill
    profile1.zipB = zipBill
    profile1.cityB = cityBill

    profile1.firstNameS = firstNameShip
    profile1.lastNameS = lastNameShip
    profile1.phoneS = phoneShip
    profile1.address1S = address1Ship
    profile1.address2S = address2Ship
    profile1.zipS = zipShip
    profile1.cityS = cityShip

    dictionary.updateValue(profile1, forKey: pName)

}
```

UPDATE: Still a bit confused, I created a new file with the following code and am getting this.

[image]

```
class ProfileTable: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

var profiles: [String: Profile] = [:]
var indices: [String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    indices = profiles.keys.sorted()
}
}
extension ProfileTable: NSTableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return indices.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSTableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MyCell.self), for: indexPath) as MyCell
    cell.profile = profiles[indices[indexPath.row]]!
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Tables display ordered data (i.e., arrays). If your data is in dictionary format, you need to convert it to an array somehow. The obvious thing to do is to sort your dictionary entries by their key, alphabetically.

Comment: Would you suggest me to just switch to arrays altogether ? Or would there be any other way for me to display this? Thanks for the response @NicolasMiari

Comment: Not necessarily. You need to consider what is the most convenient format for your data based on its use all around your app, not just the table view.

Comment: I was just going to use either the array or dictionary as a form for storage and to display. I made gets and sets for each one of the attributes that way I can pull them out individually from objects of profiles

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use an array to index into your dictionary.  You can generate the array from the keys array property of your dictionary.  Here I have sorted by the key, but you should probably provide a closure to sort by the profile name or some other field that makes better sense.

```
    class V: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
        var profiles: [String: Profile] = [:]
        var indices: [String] = []
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            indices = profiles.keys.sorted()
        }
    }

    extension V: UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return indices.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MyCell.self), for: indexPath) as MyCell
            cell.profile = profiles[indicies[indexPath.row]]!
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would this be the same thing for NSTableViews?

Comment: Because I was on OS X , so I would need NSViewControllers instead of UI?

Comment: Not exactly, you have to modify it to use the NSTableViewDataSource methods which are different (UITableView for instance is 1 dimensional while NSTableView has a row and a column) but conceptually is the same thing: Your data is held in a dictionary and you have an array of keys into that dictionary which represents the order in which the table displays the data.

Comment: I see. Would you suggest for me to use an array instead of I am planning to not have the data displayed in any certain order? Or would the dictionary be the better choice?

Comment: Its more straight forward to use an array unless you need a dictionary for some reason, such as to eliminate duplicates.  Both ways work; choose whatever is better for the task at hand.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking of doing arrays i just could not think of a way to display them with names that the user would give them. But I will give arrays another shot. I appreciate your responses. Thank you!